# ¿Las Snapshots de rds de aws son el respaldo diario de la bd?

Tags: base-de-datos, aws

queria saber la diferencia entre dos serivcios de **AWS Backup** y los **Snapshots**, lo que se quiere resolver al final del dia es tener un backup estable de la *BD* (Aurora)  diario o cada semana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque la finalidad puede ser la misma, los servicios lo son.

AWS Backup es un servicio destinado a programar, centralizar y gestionar copias de seguridad de datos. La gestión incluye cosas como la rotación o comprobación de las mismas. El objetivo principal es tener una copiar de seguridad de la información, pero no necesariamente de la estructura de la misma.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/aws-backup/latest/devguide/whatisbackup.html

Snapshots es una funcionalidad de los volúmenes EBS que permite obtener una instantánea del disco en ese momento, incluyendo cualquier cosa escrita en el mismo. Los snapshots permiten funciones típicas de un disco, tales como recrear una máquina virtual desde ese disco.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSSnapshots.html

En el caso particular de RDS Aurora, puedes entre ambos, de manera excluyente, ya que RDS tiene su propio sistema de copias programadas en el tiempo basado en Snapshot.

Si el objetivo es almacenar copias de seguridad de únicamente RDS, snapshot es la opción recomendada, debido a que la única gestión necesaria es la de rotación (de la que se encarga el propio servicio) y que además proporciona ventajas como la restauración de la base de datos.

Comment: Entonces si yo quisiera un respaldo de mi bd del dia de ayer, podria restaurar dicha informacion con Snapshots ? :3

Comment: Aunque valdrían ambas, si, snapshot es la más sencilla, desde el propio panel de RDS puedes gestionarlas y restaurarlas.

Comment: si quisiera por ejemplo , restaurar una bd en mi local, seria mas complicado ?